# PowerShell find path to currently running host (PowerShell executable)

Tags: powershell, console

I can find the path to a running script, but I can't find the path to the running *host*. I want this because we could be running PowerShell or PowerShell Core 6 or PowerShell Core 7 from a given script, which could be running on Windows or Linux. Googling around this is not obvious (I just get pages telling me how to find the path to the running script). Does anyone know how to find the path to the running host?

Comment: the full props of a `Get-Process` call include a `.Path` property. plus, the `$ShellId` contains the type of shell you want to do a G-P call on - as does `$PSversionTable`.

Comment: That is good and thanks for that, I can build a function that can determine the host executable from `gp` and `$PSVersionTable` (not sure if `$ShellId` helps as that has same value for Core 6.2.3 and PS 5.1). I'm going to have to do a function that looks all this up but I would have throught that PS was aware of itself to just able to say "the executable that started this console is <x>". Would have thought a one-liner could resolve that...

Comment: you are welcome ... and thank you for the feedback on `$ShellId`! [*grin*]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine the *full path of the executable* that launched the process in which PowerShell runs:

```bash
# Works with both PowerShell editions, on all platforms.
(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
```

[Automatic variable `$PID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pid) contains the current process' PID (process ID).

Note: On Unix platforms, if PowerShell was started via a *symlink*, the above reports the actual location of the executable, not that of the symlink.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(Get-Process Powershell).Path
```

Or

```
Join-Path -Path "$($PSHOME)" -ChildPath "powershell.exe"
```

to get the path of running host.

Comment: The first will doesn't quite work (when I run it from Core 6.2.3 it returns the `powershell.exe` under `C:\Windows\system32`, but the `$PSHOME` solution works perfectly in both Core 6.2.3 and PS 5.1. Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way (in terms of performance) to accomplish this is with the `GetCurrentProcess` method:

```
[Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Path
```

The path of the current Powershell binary will be the output, even if PowerShell was started via a shim or a symbolic link (regardless of platform).